# Some issue with Ajax on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, hpricot, ajax-on-rails

I'm using Ruby on Rails 2.3.8. I've got a vote link that when you click it executes the following action:

```
def vote
      render :update do |page|
          page.select(".divbrian").each do |d|
            page.replace_html d, "YA SEEE"
          end

          page.select('.d_voting_links_' + params[:post_id].to_s).each do |d|
            page.replace_html d, :partial => 'post_votes/voted'
          end
          page.select('.d_vote_count_' + params[:post_id].to_s).each do |d|
            page.replace_html d, Post.find(params[:post_id]).get_vote_count
          end
      end
end
```

In the HTML, there are as much divs of class "d_voting_links_" as posts displayed in the html page.

I don't know why, after I've installed Paperclip, Rails TinyMCE, and Hpricot plugins (all of them on the latest version), these ajax requests stopped working (really crazy).

I haven't changed anything of my code, I've even checked on my previous versions in which it works and nothing had changed, but those plugins.

I've also tried to created a simple div and calling it from the same action but it didn't recognize it (it does if I delete the "." from the request, but that will search for IDs, and I need to search for class).

Do you know about any known issue between those plugins and this ajax syntax? Or maybe...do you have a clue about what the problem could be?

Comment: Is vote method getting called now? Put a breakpoint and see the flow through that method?

Comment: Yes it's. Indeed, the render :update block is being executed...but somehow it does not find any div with that class, eventhough it exists in the HTML...REALLY WEIRD

Comment: No solution, but a tip: `html_escape` the calls to `params[:post_id].to_s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why that block of code stopped working...but I've now figured out that without the `page.select` block, it will work anyway and replace all of the divs with those class names.